# E/AndroidRuntime(14021): FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-default-executor-0

Tags: flutter

Initially, the app was not crashing but it was not able to read/write from firestore. So I added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in app gradle and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` in project gradle. Also, I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in AndroidManifest.xml. But this error is occuring now.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14021): FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-default-executor-0
E/AndroidRuntime(14021): Process: com.ayushsaxena.dhira, PID: 14021
E/AndroidRuntime(14021): java.lang.AssertionError
E/AndroidRuntime(14021):    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.getResourceResolver(DnsNameResolver.java:536)
E/AndroidRuntime(14021):    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.access$500(DnsNameResolver.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime(14021):    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(14021):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(14021):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(14021):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
E/libEGL  (14021): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the JDK version, try to update it to 64bits

Comment: did you added the internet permission?

Comment: `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` != `android.permission.INTERNET`. Try the latter.

Comment: Where to write it?@Lee3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve a similar issue by adding the Firebase Bill of Materials (BOM) as dependency.

See:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom

In my case:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}
```